# When passing a string without a space to "from" parameter in ActionMailer, from name just shows email and not string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am running Action_Mailer on Rails and passing a string to the from parameter in ActionMailer. When I do it with a space

such as:

```
sender = 'Site user' #will show this label next to email
mail(from: sender , to: sender_email , subject: sender_subject)
```

It will show up as 'Site user ' in the email header

However, when I use a word without spaces for the variable sender:

```
sender = 'SiteUser' #will not show this, only email
mail(from: sender , to: sender_email , subject: sender_subject)
```

It will only show 'email@site.com' in the email header

Does anyone know what's wrong with single word strings in the from parameter?

It works fine if the single string is in the default